# "... до тех пор, пока не ..., и не ..." - нужно ли два "не"?

Tags: грамматика

"Тягостное молчание тянулось до тех пор, пока пикап **не** выехал на отсыпанную щебёнкой дорогу, а прямо перед ним **не** вырулил большой грузовик с окрашенной в белый цвет цистерной."

Не могу понять - нужно ли второе "**не**" в этом предложении, и нельзя ли его просто опустить? Да и вообще - насколько хорошо это предложение звучит?

Comment: Мужчина остаётся мужчиной до тех пор, пока не споёт и не станцует! (с) Необходимо второе отрицание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ изменен

**Варианты (дискуссионный вопрос)**

Заданное предложение – это  СПП с двумя однородными придаточными **времени** и с расчлененным союзом ДО ТЕХ ПОР, ПОКА НЕ.  Сочинительный **союз А** связывает эти  придаточные. Вопрос стоит о повторе ***ПОКА НЕ***. Дело в том, что при союзе ***А*** смысл отрицания во втором придаточном прочитывается неясно.

**Вариант 1. Союз *И*:**

*Тягостное молчание тянулось **до тех пор, пока** пикап **не выехал** на отсыпанную щебёнкой дорогу и (пока) прямо перед ним **не вырулил** большой грузовик с окрашенной в белый цвет цистерной*

**Вариант 2.  Союз *ГДЕ***

*Тягостное молчание тянулось до тех пор, **пока пикап не выехал** на отсыпанную щебёнкой дорогу, **где прямо перед ним вырулил** большой грузовик с окрашенной в белый цвет цистерной.*

**Вариант 3.  Союз *КОГДА***

*Тягостное молчание тянулось до тех пор, **пока пикап не выехал** на отсыпанную щебёнкой дорогу, **когда прямо перед ним вырулил** большой грузовик с окрашенной в белый цвет цистерной.*

Comment: Такой вариант, к сожалению, не подходит по смыслу. Он похож на исходный, но не эквивалентен. Если уж менять, то надо полностью предложение перерабатывать.
То есть грамматики нам о двойном "не" ничего конкретного не говорит?

Comment: Странно... очень странно... Это я по поводу двух НЕ. Вы исправили последний комментарий, но неужели второе НЕ не нужно? И даже в таком продолжении?  "...пока пикап не выехал на отсыпанную щебёнкой дорог и (не) повернул..."

Comment: Здесь, наверное,  нужно: союз И, глаголы близко расположены, паузы нет.  Но вот  с союзом А мне не нравится втрое НЕ. Надо где-то читать грамматику.

Comment: Не-е-т,  и с оюзом А, в заданном предложении, не читается без НЕ. (Ну-у-у... у меня не читается :))))

Comment: С двумя НЕ тоже не читается. Очень далеко расположены смысловые части "пока не, а не".  Кажется, что грузовик не совершал действие вообще.

Comment: Так вот именно – далеко. И забавно!

Comment: Мужчина остаётся мужчиной до тех пор, пока не споёт и не станцует! (с)

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Галина, что это?! Чьё это (с)? Почему?!! Со второй НЕ, конечно, споров нет.

Comment: О, господи! Нашёл такое: «О, сыны простолюдинов! Остерегайтесь пения, ибо оно лишает скромности, увеличивает страсти и уничтожает мужество. Оно действует как алкоголь и делает то, что делают дурманящие вещества. Если можете, то держитесь подальше от пения и женщин, потому что пение ведет к прелюбодеянию». Игасатуль Ляхфан. // Мама дорогая!..

Comment: Саш, ты взыскуешь истины, а я привела пример употребления, а не маму дорогую.

Comment: Sharon, спасибо! Первый вариант лучше всего, как мне кажется. Собственно, изначально это предложение и было с "и", но мне посоветовали изменить на "а", в общем, там всё окончательно запуталось. :)

Comment: Да, мне он тоже больше нравится, поэтому он вариант 1. В нем сохранена исходная грамматика. Союз И соединяет однородные придаточные.